Constant timeouts with simple php site on HostGator
I am having an ongoing issue with my site on HostGator. It is a rather simple PHP site. No database... no CMS... plain vanilla.
https://fryermachine.com
What do I need to post here to get some advice?
Source code?
TIA!
As usual, HG support is not much help. Meanwhile, I tried lots of tweaks to no avail.
There's no useful detail in the error messages from StatusCake or UptimeRobot. There was a note on HostGator that directories need index files so I added "Options -Indexes" to the htaccess.

Host Gator kept insisting the site was up 100% of the time. Finally, I sent them screenshots of Uptime Robot (https://stats.uptimerobot.com/vGCqsYAwFA) and they must have resolved whatever was causing the outages.
